# Remove empty rows in excel via connectionString

Tags: excel, import, connection-string

I am using `Connection String` to connect an Excel file to read data.

I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM [SHEET1$]
```

My problem is when user set a value in a new row and later delete it, my query returns me the row but empty.

I want my select to ignore this rows without doing something like ".... `WHERE COLUMN1 <> ''`
 `AND COLUMN2 <> ''` ...." and so on. Its possible remove empty rows without provide all column list?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not a WHERE that excludes empty values in column, not row?

Comment: edited! thanks, yes I wanna say columns instead of rows

Comment: One option would be to add a column "N" with the formula `=SIGN(COUNTA(reference_to_row_of_data))` copied down to bottom of data. This formula evaluates to 1 if there is data in the row and to 0 if there is no data. Then your query would change to `SELECT * FROM [SHEET1$] WHERE COLUMNN = 1`.

Comment: I Cant modify the sheet. I Need just to add anything to the WHERE clause. Maybe it cannot be possible and the only solution is to provide all columns name and check <> ""